# Cast each T in the IEnumerable<IGrouping<,>> to IGrouping<,>

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I receive an `IEnumerable<T>` in my code. It could be a non-grouped, flat `IEnumerable<T>` or a grouped one.

Therefore, I check whether this using my tiny, nifty little extension I wrote:

```
public static bool IsABunchOfGroups<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
  return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IGrouping<,>));
}
```

However, once checked, if it is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<,>>` I want to cast it to that so that each T in the `IEnumerable<T>` is cast to IGrouping<,> where I don't know what the generic type arguments of the `IGrouping<,>` are.

I am struggling to do that.

So, here's what I want:

```
void WriteSequenceToStream(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
  if (sequence.IsABunchOfGroups())
  {
    foreach(var t in sequence)
    {
      // t as IGrouping<,>
    }
  }
}
```

Once again, not being sure what the generic type arguments are, it is pointless for me to even use the `dynamic` keyword in this context like so:

```
void WriteSequenceToStream(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
  if (sequence.IsABunchOfGroups())
  {
    foreach(var t in sequence)
    {
      // t as IGrouping<,>
      dynamic element = t;

      someTextWriter.WriteLine(element.Key);

      foreach(dynamic item in element)
      {
        // Oh yeah, may be I could! Anyway, still
        // is there a way I could do it without the dynamic keyword?

        // I think I am asking a question I've asked in the past
        // many times already, in one form or another
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do you intend to flatten the list? if not then are all the groups in `IEnumerable<IGrouping<,>>` have same key type and same data type? if not then how do you expect `IEnumerable<IGrouping<,>>` to be transformed to `IGrouping<,>`. If I am not wrong you may want to get all the elements whether grouped or not, correct if I understood it incorrectly.

Comment: I do not want to cast the `IEnumerable<IGrouping<,>>` into an `IGrouping<,>`. I want to cast each element in the `IEnumerable<IGrouping<,>>` into an `IGrouping<,>`.

Comment: Since the type of key and elements are unknown to you, I wonder what is your purpose to cast into an `IGrouping<,>`? get the key of group or even more?. I guess since types are unknown the cast may be achieved through reflection. I'll give a try here and come back if I have something for you.

Comment: Is it even meaningful to know the *value* of the key if you don't know its *meaning*? It's impossible to trace back which entity/property was used in the grouping.

Comment: @GertArnold: you're right. The whole question and scenario is pointless. I changed my design soon after posting the question. I just left the question as is because now I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: @PushprajRuhal: Thanks, please don't spend any time on it. It is a pointless exercise. I changed my design soon after posting this question and realizing what the pitfall was. You're right about the apparent lack of purpose in getting the type arguments when one does not even know their *meaning* so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
Collection.Select(item => (TheTypeYouWant)item);
```

?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but I would be required to know (and to tell the compiler) the actual type arguments of the closed generic type I want to transform/project into, right? So, I can't write `sequence.Select(item => (IGrouping<,>)item);` can I?

Comment: If this is a T issue (eg. CastToT<T> (IEnumerable collection)), you can just cast to T. (item => (T) item)